# focus on ASP dropdown using javascript/jquery on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dropdown

I am trying to focus on ASP dropdown on page loads using javascript/jquery. I can do it via code behind using `DDL_Department.Focus()` method. But I am trying using javascript/jquery.

I tried three several approaches but not successful with any of them. Please see the code.

```
<asp:Content ID="UserContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Department</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Department" class="form-control input_text" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="--Select Department--" Value="" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<script>
        //first approach
        //not successful
        $(function () {
            $('# <%= DDL_Department.ClientID %>').focus();
        });
        //////
        //second approach
        //not successful
        $(function () {
            $('#DDL_Department').focus();
        });
        //////
        //third approach
        //not successful
        $(function () {
            $("[id$=DDL_Department]").focus();
        });
        //////

    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is the space in here between the '#' and the '<' deliberate? `$('# <%= DDL_Department.ClientID %>').focus();` there shouldn't be a space.

Comment: Try `$("[id$=DDL_Department]").click();` instead of `.focus()`

Comment: None of the solution is working. I can not understand who has negative marked my question. If you can it will be better to provide the solution or give some comment for the reason of negative markings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing:

```
$(function () {
        $('# <%= DDL_Department.ClientID %>').focus();
    });
```

to:

```
$(function () {
        $('#<%= DDL_Department.ClientID %>').focus();
    });
```

(removing the white space after pound character)

Answer (score -1):

You could just use

```
$('#DDL_Department').focus();
```

without anything else.

Comment: It works fine. Otherwise you'll have to add a handler function. Also make sure you jquery file is loading.

Comment: What's handler function?